# Get list of connected printers

Tags: 14.04, usb, printing

So, I understand that I can list all printers with

```
$ lpstat -p -d
printer DYMO-LabelWriter-450-Turbo is idle.  enabled since Tue 06 Jun 2017 12:12:48 PM SGT
Waiting for printer to become available.
printer DYMO-LabelWriter-450-Turbo-2 is idle.  enabled since Tue 06 Jun 2017 12:12:31 PM SGT
Ready to print.
printer Epson-Stylus-NX420 is idle.  enabled since Mon 18 May 2015 05:23:36 AM SGT
printer Photosmart-C4200-series is idle.  enabled since Thu 11 May 2017 07:17:13 PM SGT
system default destination: Photosmart-C4200-series
```

DYMO-LabelWriter-450-Turbo is installed but disconnected and DYMO-LabelWriter-450-Turbo-2 is both installed and connected.

What is the cleanest way to get the list of connected printers? Parsing the output of lpstat for "Ready to print."? Or is there some clean approach using lsusb?

Comment: Would a command like `lpstat -p -d | grep "Ready to print"` work?

Comment: @ThatGuy: "Ready to print" is on a newline so that might not work if others want the printer names. But what you're saying is essentially the same idea as my current solution (your idea but in python to grab the printer names more easily). I guess I thought there was some mechanism where lpstat (or some other command) would report connected printers without any grep-ing.

Answer (score 0):

`lpstat` will list printers that are being serviced by cups.  I see that you have an *HP Photosmart* which I believe does not use cups.

Since you will most often be printing from a GUI app such as Libre or Firefox, I've found that clicking on *System Settings > Printers** provides the most useful information.

For cups printers, `lpstat -t` should give  you the maximum amount of current information about all the relevant printers your machine knows about.